# Pandas: remove groups based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to remove groups from my pandas dataframe when conditions are met. For example, this data set, whenever a customer answers `i` to question `a` I need to remove the entire records from this customer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': [1, 1, 2], 'question': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'answer': ['i', 'ii', 'iii']})
df
    customer    question    answer
0   1           a           i
1   1           b           ii
2   2           a           iii
```

So for this case, I need to filter out like this.

```
    customer    question    answer
0   2           a           iii
```

What is a good way to achieve this? Only the way I can think of is to pivot, filter, and melt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [226]: df[~df.customer.isin(df.loc[df.answer.eq('i') & df.question.eq('a'),'customer'].unique())]
Out[226]:
  answer  customer question
2    iii         2        a
```

Comment: where do you check if `question`=a?

Comment: Both [maxu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu)'s as well as [wen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/wen)'s  answers are great! I am going to choose this as the solution based on the speed. For my 500k data set, [maxu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu)'s solution took 83.1ms whereas [wen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/wen)'s 29.6s.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by `filter`

```
df.groupby('customer').filter(lambda x : ~((x.answer=='i')&(x.question=='a')).any())

Out[109]: 
  answer  customer question
2    iii         2        a
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it also like this (without costum functions):

```
df[~df['customer'].isin(df[df['question']+df['answer']=='ai']['customer'].values)]
```

output:

```
Out[343]: 
  answer  customer question
2    iii         2        a
```

Comment: Interesting, did not think of this way. Only the thing is that both `question` and `answer ` have to be str. For this case it's ok though.

Comment: you can always convert any variable to a string (using .astype('str') so that for example str(1)+str(2)='12')

Comment: Yes makes sense. Thanks!